# SED find and replace element in filename with incremental values

Tags: sed, regular-expression, filenames, jenkins, maven

A sample filename is `Sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` (result of a maven build in jenkins).

My goal is to run a shell script that executes on failure and what that script does it adds incremental numbers to the filename.

So lets say something like `Sample-0.0.1-1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, `Sample-0.0.1-2-SNAPSHOT.jar`.. etc.

(BTW: In order to produce the filename, Jenkins uses the following format for environment variables to fetch the related info from the POM file: $POM_ARTIFACTID-$POM-VERSION.jar)

I was thinking somehow using $POM-VERSION to echo it out and use sed to add/replace the incremental numbers?

Problem is that I don't know how to execute that, so if someone can help me out on this one that would be great! Also if there's a better idea I'm definitely open for it.

Comment: Its not clear to me exactly what you want.  Is the shell script passed the filename?  Does it move files?  Does it just echo a new filename based on one from the environment variables you mentioned?

Comment: Ah, my bad. What I meant was I want to be able to change the artifact filename + change the version tag in the pom file.

Comment: My guess is that the easiest way is to increment the number and write to a temp file in the workspace then everytime the build is run it fetches that number and inputs it in the the filename + pom file... and so on.

Comment: What do you mean with "a shell script that executes on failure"?  What is the big picture here?  It seems to me you are trying to do things under the hood that jenkins should solve for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the workspace is persistent, here's a thing to trigger after each build:

```
if [ -f counterfile.txt ]; then
  num=$(cat counterfile.txt)
else
  num=0
fi
num=$((num+1))
echo $num>counterfile.txt

filename=$POM_ARTIFACTID-$POM-VERSION.jar
newfilename=echo $filename | sed "s/-SNAPSHOT/-$num-SNAPSHOT/"
mv $filename $newfilename
```

Comment: should "echo num..." be "echo $num..." ?

Comment: Yes it should. Editing.